# Function's parameters in JS ext

Tags: javascript, extjs

It's my first time with JS Ext (Sencha) and I've one problem. I 've define a test function, which receives a parameter, that is a string, it is as follows:

```
function testlistener(p) {
       Ext.Msg.alert('testing', p.toString());
}
```

What I see into the alert pop up is just "object object" istead of the string, I have the same result if i just use:

```
Ext.Msg.alert('testing', p);
```

and I have tried many other ways, but none of them work, so I don't know how is the object structure, and I'm not able to find it on the api.

Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you're not actually passing a string to your function but something different. See what `typeof p` returns, I'm guessing `"object"`. Make sure you are actually passing a string and not an object.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try asap, now I'm not able to do it.
For more info, I'm calling the function like:

testlistener('test string');